# Extract Data between comma

Tags: text-processing, awk, data

I have an output file which contains different numbers separated by commas. The issue is I do not know the number of commas.

I would in turn like this data to be grep on another file. For example:

I have INFO: `10,20,30,55,58,47,52,100`

I use

```
awk '{split($0,a,","); for (i=1; i<=8; i++) print a[i]}' TMPFILE
```

to extract the data. But I do not know how long the `for` loop has to be performed.

Once I get those numbers like 10, I need to `grep` that on data.txt
then 20 on data.txt and so on until the last number.

Comment: For future reference, this kind of data is called "CSV" data (for "Comma Separated Value").  Might be useful to know that if you are doing internet searches related to processing it, since CSV processing is a common task.

Answer (score 3):

akw:

```
echo '10,20,30,55,58,47,52,100' | \
awk '{x=split($0,a,","); for (i=1; i <= x; ++i) print a[i]}'
```

awk using field separator:

```
echo '10,20,30,55,58,47,52,100' | \
awk -F ',' '{for(i=1; i <= NF; ++i) print $i}'
```

sed:

```
 echo '10,20,30,55,58,47,52,100' | sed 's/,/\n/g'
```

---

So, then the command would be e.g.:

```
sed 's/,/\n/g' TMPFILE | xargs -I'{}' grep '{}' data.txt
```

Or, as using `xargs` perhaps:

```
xargs -a TMPFILE -d, -I'\x' grep '\x\{1\}' data.txt
```

Or, if you do not want to use `xargs` perhaps; making pattern file with sed:

```
sed 's/\([^,]\+\),*/^\1$\n/g' TMPFILE | \
grep -o -f /proc/self/fd/0 data.txt
```

Or,

```
tr ',' '\n' < TMPFILE | \
grep -f /proc/self/fd/0 data.txt
```

All depending on what and how you want to grep.

Comment: Huh? The `grep` could be only `grep -oE '[^,]+' TMPFILE`.

Comment: @manatwork: Yes, but not for fulfilling last requirement: *"Once I get those numbers like 10, I need to grep that on data.txt then 20 on data.txt and so on untill the last number."*

Answer (score 1):

If want to repeatedly grep the same file, you could also try a shell loop:

```
IFS=,
for i in $(cat csvfile)
do
  grep "$i" datafile
done > outfile
```

---

If you do not put it in a script or a subshell you need to

```
oldIFS=$IFS
```

before and

```
IFS=$oldIFS
```

afterwards..